# Можете ли вы сказать мне, могу ли я использовать компонент Chip в Autocmplete, но чтобы Chip не был множественным числом

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Доброе утро, не могли бы вы сказать мне, могу ли я использовать компонент Chip в Autocmplete, но чтобы Chip не имел множественного числа Пробовал использовать renderTags, но с множественными не работает, что логично

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском

Comment: Доброе утро, не могли бы вы сказать мне, могу ли я использовать компонент Chip в Autocmplete, но чтобы Chip не имел множественного числа

Пробовал использовать renderTags, но с множественными не работает, что логично